# Is it possible to connect a signal from any instance of class1 to a slot in class 2?

Tags: qt, signals, connect

For exmaple we have `class Item` which has signal `void reportError(QString)`.
Furthermore we have class `ItemController` with slot `void showError(QString)`.

Is it possible to connect a signal from any instance of `class Item` to a slot of `ItemController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You have to call `connect()` for every instance.

Comment: is there any way with one call of connect?

Comment: Put 'connect' code into Item's contructor (pass ItemController& there). Best way =)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @scai you can but you have to call connect for every instance. If one of your classes is an atributte of the other you can do it in the constructor very easily, or in the funcition or class where they get instantiated just do a connect right after that.